# Ionic plugin development best practices

Tags: ios, angularjs, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm creating an iOS & Android plugin for an ionic project I'm working on. The problem/question I'm having is that every time I change something in the plugin I have to remove and add the plugin again. It's kinda time consuming to remove and add the plugin every time I change something I want to test.

If I want to log something or just change one character in the iOS plugin and want to test it in the ionic app I have to do:

```
ionic plugin remove myplugin
ionic plugin add myplugin
ionic build ios
```

Is there no better way to develop a ionic plugin without the time consuming removing and adding the plugin? I know of `ionic state restore` but that seems to remove and add the plugins and the platforms which takes longer than my above solution.

Comment: This is interesting, But i think ionic doesn't support something like you want right now. It would be nice if someone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can work directly in your plugin from directory "platforms".
Ex: `myApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/MyPlugin`.

And in the end you must move your code into plugin from directory "plugins".
Ex: `myApp/plugins/MyPlugin`

My solution will help you not execute all commands for every change you make.

I hope to help you with my above solution. And sorry for my English.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now if I want to change something only in the plugin, I work directly from Xcode and if it works I copy that code to the plugin. But when I change something in the plugin and the app I always need to run the above commands.